# show and hide two xibs in same view controller on respective button click in ios swift

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

i have a view controller in which i have taken a view and in that view i have two buttons and below that view i have a collection view. i have create 2 custom xibs for each respective button click. by default for button 1 i have set xib 1 but when i click button 2 then dont know how to show xib 2

screenshot result for button 1:
[image: screenshot for categories button]

screenshot result for button 2:
[image: screenshot for stores button]

screenshot for categories xib:
[[image: screenshot for category xib]

screenshot for store xib:
[image: screenshot for store xib]

my code in view controller file is:

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var store_bar: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var store_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_bar: UIViewX!

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryColView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // register collectionview cell
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1")
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoresCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell")

        self.store_bar.isHidden = true

    }

    @objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        }
    }

    @IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = true
        self.store_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func categoriesData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
        self.store_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    }
}




extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1
            cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
            cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

           return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3, height: 93)
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to change the content of the collection view when you switch between Categories and Stores?

Comment: Yes my content should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hide the `categoryColView` in `storeData` method

Change isSelected property of `category_title`, `store_title` buttons on selection and reload the collection view.

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var store_bar: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var store_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_title: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var category_bar: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryColView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // register collectionview cell
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1")
        self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoresCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell")
        storeData(store_title)
    }
    @objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        }
    }
    @IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        category_title.isSelected = false
        store_title.isSelected = true
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = true
        self.store_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
        self.categoryColView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func categoriesData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        category_title.isSelected = true
        store_title.isSelected = false
        self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
        self.store_bar.isHidden = true
        self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.category_bar.isHidden = false
        self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
        self.categoryColView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In collection view data source and delegate methods check isSelected status of the `category_title`, `store_title` buttons and perform actions based on that.

```
extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        if category_title.isSelected {
//            return category count
//        } else {
//            return store count
//        }
        return 20
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if category_title.isSelected {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1
            cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
            cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
            cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! StoresCell
            //...
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you dequeue only "CategoryCell1" in your collectionView.

One thing you can do is to create an Enum e.g: TypeCells

```
enum TypeCells {
 case categorie
 case store
}
```

Then you can in your Controller initialise a variable e.g:

```
var typeCell: TypeCells = .categorie
```

Then in your IBAction, you can modify you variable, e.g:

```
@IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        typeCell = .data
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

And next you just need to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch typeCell {
     case categorie:
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1
    // what you want to display

     case storie:
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1
    // what you want to display

    }
```

Have fun ! :)